# ODS EXCEL.TAGSET title statement

Tags: excel, report, reporting, sas

I would like to print some text before I show the result of a proc report. ODS is excel.tagset. Currently I do it with the title statement. But the title statement is limited to 10 titles (title1 title2,...). However I need more than 10 textlines at the output. How can I do this? I have SAS9.2.

EDIT:
Here is a code example:

```
ods tagsets.excelxp STYLE=sasdocprinter file=_WEBOUT
     options(embedded_titles='yes' embedded_footnotes='yes');

title1 'title text row1';
title2 'title text row2';
...
title10 "title text &macro_var.";

footnote1 'footnote text';

proc report data=lib.a;
   ...
run;
```

Comment: What sort of text are you talking about including?  How are you putting data out to the tagset in the first place?

Comment: I edited my question with the asked information. Each title statement generates a new line. That is what I want to do. But it is limited to 10 lines. However I have to print more lines before the proc report...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are using `PROC REPORT`, the easiest way around this may be to have PROC REPORT handle the lines of text.  In `PROC REPORT`, you have the option of doing `compute before _PAGE_`, which will execute prior to each time a page is begun - suspiciously like a title.

```
proc report nowd data=sashelp.class;
columns sex name age height;
define sex/group;
define name/display;
define age /display;
define height/display;
compute before _PAGE_;
line "Title Row 11";
line "Title Row 12";
endcomp;
run;
```

Depending on your output destination there may be a row between the title and the proc report line, you can control that in some destinations (ie, remove it) with options if it is undesirable (or alternately move ALL of your title to lines like this).

Comment: Thanx! I have generated a new dataset and print it with an additional proc report but your solution also works fine.